# Coldfusion server is working fine but one site goes down just around two minutes

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We are using coldfusion 10 server for web applications. it has many sites which were working fine but suddenly one site goes down just after the coldfusion server reboots and displays the message

```
The service is unavailable.
Service Temporary Unavailable!

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.






  Jakarta/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.32 ()
```

I have checked the system error log and i found the following messages there

```
    2014 8:23:10 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@7870cbee]) and a value of type [coldfusion.runtime.RequestInfo] (value [coldfusion.runtime.RequestInfo@41542d45]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
May 23, 2014 8:23:10 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [coldfusion.util.DateUtils$1] (value [coldfusion.util.DateUtils$1@4bc7650c]) and a value of type [java.util.GregorianCalendar] (value [java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=450000000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=false,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=?,MONTH=?,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=?,HOUR=?,HOUR_OF_DAY=?,MINUTE=?,SECOND=?,MILLISECOND=?,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
May 23, 2014 8:23:10 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@17bd3a0a]) and a value of type [coldfusion.sql.DataSrcImpl] (value [coldfusion.sql.DataSrcImpl@7d682e84]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
May 23, 2014 8:23:10 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@5fc549f6]) and a value of type [coldfusion.monitor.util.RequestMonitorData] (value [coldfusion.monitor.util.RequestMonitorData@42c61c6e]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

The amazing thing is that only one site is getting down,  all other work fine, is there something wrong with the code or some other issue?

Comment: You need to give more details, about no of sites running, how is the connector created, exception.log trace, server.log info

Comment: One important thing i find that site becomes unresponsive under higher load. it seems that IIS fails to connect with JRUN under high stress. Site works fine when traffic is low. Other sites on the same server work fine. I was using the individual connector in IIS for each site. I changed it to "All" but nothing happens. Site is still going down under normal or higher stress.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Tomcat (and Solr?), it looks like that's where these errors are coming from. Your cold fusion app may not be properly handling errors returned to it from that service - maybe look at where those services interface, try to introduce some error handling, and go from there?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3556864 and is more or less related. You need to tune your jvm first (if you are getting traces of Out of Memory in the logs), else please tune your connectors. Refer to http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/tuning-coldfusion-10-iis-connector-configuration or for a more detailed explanation, refer to http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-11-iis-connector-tuning.

Hope this helps.